# Get text from closest selected dropdown option with class on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many dropdowns, when I click the button I want it to look up the select option that is selected and alert me the text it says, like 'grape'.

It must use .closest, have tried many variations but cant seem to find it.....

```
<select name="div0" class="dropdowns">
  <option value="orange">orange</option>
  <option value="apple">apple</option>
  <option value="grape">grape</option>
  <option value="peas">peas</option>
</select>

<input type="button" name="mybutton" value="Edit Row">

<select name="div1" class="dropdowns">
  <option value="orange">orange</option>
  <option value="apple">apple</option>
  <option value="grape">grape</option>
  <option value="peas">peas</option>
</select>

<input type="button" name="mybutton" value="Edit Row" class="editrowbutton">

JQUERY (Nearest I can get)
$(document).on('click', '.editrowbutton', function() {

     var thetext =  $(this).closest('select').find('option:selected').text();

    alert(thetext);
});
```

Comment: where is the element with editrowbutton class?

Comment: `closest` only works to find itself or the closest parent that matches the selector. Its like `parents` but looks at itself and up and stops once it finds a match. Or continues all the way up and finds nothing.

Comment: @Vanojx I added the class in the button (this was not the issue) , my mistake, end of day and all that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the class editrowbutton on your buttons in the example.

use `.prev` to get the previous element from target.

```
$(document).on('click', '.editrowbutton', function() {
    var thetext =  $(this).prev().find('option:selected').text();
    alert(thetext);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/wt00c2wu/

`.closest` looks up the tree at parents. Since the select is not a parent you will not return anything.

If you wanted to search the siblings you can use `prev('selector')` or `next('selector')` as well.

https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: Cant beat a working fiddle, and to think I was chasing '.closest'

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the data-* attribute, preventing DOM position mistakes.

```js
$(function(){
    
  $(document).on("click",'.editrowbutton',function(){
    var target = $(this).data("select");
    alert($('select[name='+target+'] option:selected').text())
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="div0" class="dropdowns">
  <option value="orange">orange</option>
  <option value="apple">apple</option>
  <option value="grape">grape</option>
  <option value="peas">peas</option>
</select>

<input type="button" name="mybutton" data-select="div0" class="editrowbutton" value="Edit Row">

<select name="div1" class="dropdowns">
  <option value="orange">orange</option>
  <option value="apple">apple</option>
  <option value="grape">grape</option>
  <option value="peas">peas</option>
</select>

<input type="button" name="mybutton" data-select="div1" class="editrowbutton" value="Edit Row">
```